# Symbolicate iOS Crashlog of Development Version

Tags: ios, symbolicatecrash, crash-log

I've compiled and run an app on the iPad (Build Configuration is `Debug`). Then I've quit the app and disconnected the iPad. Then I started the app on the iPad again, and somewhen a crash happened.

In the crashlog, though, are only hex addresses for my app. Can I still symbolicate those? I didn't touch the project inbetween.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running OS X Lion (likely if you're using the latest Xcode)?
If so, your ~/Library folder is hidden by default, and this makes the .dSYM folder invisible.
Open a Terminal and try

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library/
```

and see if this helps.  It worked for me.

Comment: it works now! could be that it worked already as i didn't check recently, but probably this nailed it. thank you scott!

Answer (score 0):

Drag & Drop the crashlog in Xcode. It should be automatically symbolicated by Xcode itself.

Also read [this TechNote](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html) for more information

Comment: No, it does not. I've got the crashlog in XCode 4 Organizer -> Devices -> Device Logs. Dragging it to the XCode Icon in the dock just opens the text of the crashlog in an XCode editor, memory addresses still not symbolicated.

Comment: Do you still have the symbols (.dSYM) file next to your generated code? Also, try running the symbolicatecrash script directly from the terminal (see other subjects in SO like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681042/symbolicatecrash)

Comment: I'm using a development version I just compiled - afaik the dSYM only gets created when I archive, right? But I archived afterwards, and tried to `symbolicatecrash -v˜, but it gives the warning that it can't find a matching unstripped binary.

Comment: No, the dSYM is created every time you compile. Except if you unckecked the "generate symbols file" in the Build Settings of your project -- but it is checked by default). You are saying that you archived afterwards, that's too bad, that means that you regenerated a compilation (with a new dSYM that got generated and lost the previous one), and of course then symbols & addresses won't match your crashlog you want to symbolicate.

Comment: Ok, but even before I archived and recompiled, I watched the crashlog in Xcode's Organizer - and there were hex addresses. Would I have had to drag that crashlog somewhere else to get symbolized?

Comment: No it should be symbolicated automagically... at least normally. You should read this TechNote: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: I"ve had the "DerivedData" folder excluded from Spotlight searches due to another tutorial for symbolication. Maybe that's why no symbolication happened, let's wait for the next crash...